# actions done sequentially in the past

Tags: tense

> I **received** your feedback form, and I **completed** the changes and **sent** it
>   back for your review again.
>
> I **received** your feedback form, and I **have completed** the changes and **sent** it
>   back for your review again.

The three actions (received, completed, sent) are done sequentially in the past. Are the tenses used in both sentences correct?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, they're both fine. They differ slightly in meaning. In the second one, the completing and sending back both happened fairly recently. That subtle suggestion is absent from the first sentence's meaning.